# Different in exercises between two 100pushups sites

Tags: push-ups, websites

I have found two different sites guiding how to achieve 100 push ups: HundredPushups.com and Alternative100Pushups.com. However they have different schedule. For example, if you get into the 11-20 pushups round in your first test, numbers of pushups in each set W1D1 in [HundredPushups.com](http://hundredpushups.com/week1.html) are 10 12 7 7 and max (at least 9), meanwhile in [Alternative100Pushups.com](http://www.alternative100pushups.com/alternative-100-push-ups-programme/11-20-push-ups) are 8 9 7 7 and max (at least 8). Do you know why there is a derivation? Which plan should I stick to?

Comment: Or maybe try the Grease and Groove method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find that there are many paths to the same goal.  Both of these choose similar, but slightly different paths toward the goal of 100 push ups.  The Alternative plan opts to start with lower volume at first to help you get acclimated to it.

I would use Alterantive100Pushups.com if I'm not used to working my arms and chest, or a rank beginner.  I might use HundredPushups.com if I'm acclimated to doing volume work already.

If you aren't sure, just ask yourself if the progression gives you any concerns about being able to finish.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just a normal person who has no interest of being masculine but just want to stay healthy. Do you think that this approach will help me?

Comment: Being generally active will help you stay healthy.  100 pushups is a lot of hard work, and will likely put some bulk on your arms.  The biggest thing is that you find something that helps you stay motivated.  A program like this can be a good idea as you have a goal you are working towards.